# Using Bullet Physics to Load OBJ model to btGImpactMeshShape but the result is wrong

Tags: polygon, game-physics, mesh, bullet, wavefront

I use Bullet Physics Engine to load OBJ model to the world using btGImpactMeshShape..
I am very new using this engine

Here is my code

```
//---------------------------------------//

//            load from obj              //

//---------------------------------------//

ConvexDecomposition::WavefrontObj wobj;
printf("load first try"); fflush( stdout );
std::string filename("bunny.obj");
int result = wobj.loadObj( "bunny.obj" );
if(!result)
{
printf("first try fail\n"); fflush( stdout );
printf("load second try");  fflush( stdout );
result = wobj.loadObj("../bunny.obj");
}

printf("--load status %d\n", result );
printf("--triangle: %d\n", wobj.mTriCount);
printf("--vertex: %d\n", wobj.mVertexCount);


btTriangleIndexVertexArray* colonVertexArrays = new btTriangleIndexVertexArray(
wobj.mTriCount,
wobj.mIndices,
                3*sizeof(int),
                wobj.mVertexCount,
                wobj.mVertices,
                3*sizeof(float)
                );

btGImpactMeshShape* bunnymesh = new btGImpactMeshShape(colonVertexArrays);
bunnymesh ->setLocalScaling( btVector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) );
bunnymesh ->updateBound();
startTransform.setOrigin( btVector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );
startTransform.getBasis().setEulerZYX( 0, 0, 0 );
localCreateRigidBody( bunnymesh , startTransform, 0.0 );
printf("Load done...\n");
```

Here in the model that I loaded .............. this bunny was viewed using MeshLab on MAC

[image: original bunny model viewed by Meshlab]

I tried to change various stride parameters, however this is the result from my program

[image: using bullet to view Bunny]
[image: Console output]

Do you have any suggestions what wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't wobj.mVertices a pointer to a double array? btTriangleIndexVertexArray expects a pointer to float, so you'll have to create a new float array and copy and cast the vertices in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However how could i set the pointer to float. Is the problem related to my model? or do I have to change any parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Blender names its indices starting at 1 while Bullet Physics starts at 0.
As an illustration, here below a cube mesh exported from Blender, then rendered as `btGImpactMeshShape` and 3 cubes rendered as `btBoxShape`. Also below how the vertices and indices for `btTriangleIndexVertexArray` should look like for a cube mesh to render properly in Bullet Physics as  `btGImpactMeshShape`. For more, click on the link to see a similar thread on the [Bullet Physics forum.](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11922&p=40158#p40158)

To learn more about `btTriangleIndexVertexArray` and  `btGImpactMeshShape`, also see in the Bullet Physics SDK the GimpactTestDemo which showcases a torus and... the Standford bunny.

```
const int NUMBER_VERTICES = 8;
const int NUMBER_TRIANGLES = 12;

static float cubeVertices[NUMBER_VERTICES * 3] = {
    1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,
    1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000,
   -1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000,
   -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,
    1.000000, 1.000000, -0.999999,
    0.999999, 1.000000, 1.000001,
   -1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000,
   -1.000000, 1.000000, -1.000000
};

static int cubeIndices[NUMBER_TRIANGLES][3] = {
   { 1, 3, 0 },
   { 7, 5, 4 },
   { 4, 1, 0 },
   { 5, 2, 1 },
   { 2, 7, 3 },
   { 0, 7, 4 },
   { 1, 2, 3 },
   { 7, 6, 5 },
   { 4, 5, 1 },
   { 5, 6, 2 },
   { 2, 6, 7 },
   { 0, 3, 7 }
};
```

[image]